# Can i use xampp to open my hmvc codeigniter project on mobile?

Tags: php, mobile, xampp, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I have made a web application to store patient records for a doctor and i am using xampp to host it locally.Using xampp i can access my login page of the application just fine by putting my pc's ip address in the mobile's browser and the path to login page but when i enter the username and password and touch login it says this site can't be reached.It works fine on pc but on mobile only login page can be accessed.I have been using codeigniter(hmvc) to build this application.i am connecting them to the same wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use access your application running on xampp on your mobile just the case that your php application and mobile has to be connected on same network.

Comment: yes i am connecting them to the same network still only login page is opening and when i enter the coprrect username and password and touch on login it says the site can't be reached it is working fine on my pc its giving this error only on mobile.